# Results in “generalised smooth spaces” that did not hold in the case of smooth manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory

Consider the category of smooth manifolds $\text{Man}$. I quote from n-lab page:

> Manifolds are fantastic spaces. It’s a pity that there aren’t more of them.

I understand that this category $\text{Man}$ is not well behaved in more than one sense or do not have enough objects, for it to be

- closed under pullback,
- to have mapping space, an appropriate smooth structure on $\text{Map}(X,Y)$ for manifolds $X$ and $Y$.

Then, people **added** more spaces to the category of manifolds, in an attempt to make sure the resulting category has (some) of the nice properties which the category $\text{Man}$ did not had. Some examples are

1. Chen spaces ([On the proof of "Mapping space is a Chen space"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363605/on-the-proof-of-mapping-space-is-a-chen-space?noredirect=1#comment917398_363605)),
2. Differentiable spaces (I saw the first in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605694.pdf), section $2.7$) which are sheaves over the category $\text{Man}$ that are Differentiable stacks over the category $\text{Man}$ (recall that, any manifold is a sheaf over the category $\text{Man}$ that are Differentiable stacks over the category $\text{Man}$).
3. Frölicher spaces. These are introduced to have a Cartesian closed category (please correct me if I have misunderstood something).

Question : Are there any (What are the) results that hold in these generalised spaces whose counterparts does not hold true in the set up of smooth manifolds?

There is one result (Lemma $2.35$ in above paper) I am aware of that holds true for Differentiable spaces but there is no appropriate counterpart for smooth manifolds.

Sub questions :

1. It looks like diffeological spaces are introduced not to “enrich” (not sure if it is correct word) the category of manifolds, but actually to study sheaves on the category of manifolds. Is that correct? I am not sure to what extent this question is making sense, so feel free to ask for more clarification or ignore it.
2. I also observe similarity with the notion of “Algebriac spaces”. Those were also (roughly) defined (similar to Differentiable spaces) as sheaves of particular kind (over some appropriate site). I think there are more than a handful of results that holds true in Algebriac spaces but not in the category $\text{Sch}/S$. You can also add them, but I am not sure if I can appreciate them enough.

Comment: I could not find Lemma 2.7. In the link you provided it is Example 2.7.

Comment: Fixed @AdittyaChaudhuri it is Lemma 2.35

Comment: Maybe not exactly an answer to your question, but [Freed-Hopkins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5959) prove that Chern-Weil forms are the only natural differential forms associated to a connection on a principal bundle. To both precisely formulate and to prove the theorem, they require the language of simplicial sheaves on the site of smooth manifolds. I don't know how that notion of "generalized manifold" compares to the ones you're asking about, though.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik According to the question above you mentioned (3) "Frölicher spaces. These are introduced to have a Cartesian closed category (please correct me if I have misunderstood something)."...            But category of Chen spaces(1) is also Cartesian Closed..... Also I guess(though don't have the reference or proof right now..so may be wrong) the same is true for Differentiable space(2).... So it is for sure  that "forming a Cartesian Closed Category" cannot be the reason for introducing Frölicher spaces .

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri Yes, there are other categories which are Cartesian closed (and which have embedding from smooth manifolds)... I did not say it is the only reason. I only know that reason, so I mentioned it :)

Comment: @ArunDebray Hey, thanks.. I think your reference to Freed-Hopkins paper is very relevant (could be one of the motivations for Dimitri Pavlov's answer).. I have heard about that before but I have not read... It looks like it is now time to read that :)

Answer (score 8):

There are many such results.

Consider some smooth manifolds M and N.
The internal hom Hom(M,N) is a sheaf on smooth manifolds.
We can compute its tangent bundle,
and it turns out that the tangent space at some point f in Hom(M,N),
i.e., f:M→N is a smooth map, equals the vector space
of smooth sections of the vector bundle f*TN.
This is the expected result, but the setting of sheaves allows us to make it completely rigorous and precise with minimal technicalities.

Now take M=N and consider the open subobject of Hom(M,M) consisting of diffeomorphisms.
This is a group object (i.e., an infinite-dimensional Lie group)
and its Lie algebra is precisely the Lie algebra of vector fields on M.

Differential k-forms form a sheaf Ω^k on smooth manifolds.
In particular, morphisms Hom(M,N)→Ω^k are differential k-forms on the infinite-dimensional space of smooth maps M→N.
We also immediately obtain the de Rham complex on Hom(M,N)
in the same manner, and it satisfies the expected properties.

Liekwise, we have a sheaf of groupoids B_∇(G) of principal G-bundles
with connection.
Maps Hom(M,N)→B_∇(G) are principal G-bundles with connection
over the infinite-dimensional space of smooth maps M→N.

Hopkins and Freed compute the de Rham complex of B_∇(G),
and it turns out to be the vector space of invariant polynomials
on the Lie algebra of G.

This means, for instance, that you can immediately start
computing Chern–Weil forms of principal G-bundles with connection
on Hom(M,N), for example.

Now, we can also take G to be any group object in sheaves,
such as, for example, the group Diff(M) of diffeomorphisms
of M considered above.
This immediately allows us to consider principal G-bundles
with connection for such groups.

Other objects that can be encoded in this setting
include the (higher) sheaves of bundle (n-1)-gerbes with connection
and structure abelian Lie group A, denoted by B_∇^n(A).
Morphisms M→B_∇^n(A) are precisely bundle (n-1)-gerbes with connection over M.

Now you can talk about bundle (n-1)-gerbes with connection over Hom(M,N).
The Cheeger–Simons differential refinement of the Chern character
in this language is a morphism B_∇(G)→B_∇^n(A), etc.

So in particular, not only de Rham cohomology, but also differential cohomology make sense in this framework.

Comment: This is interesting.. For manifolds $M.N$, as the mapping space $\text{Map}(M,N)$ is not expected to have a nice smooth structure, you would like to see $M$ and $N$ as objects of the category $Sh(\text{Man})$ and taking then take the internal-hom object of $M,N$ (I do not know why it exists, I will check details; I guess here "the tensor" is tensor product of sheaves)..

Comment: I have some other questions, but I should at least read the Freed-Hopkins paper first :) Thanks for this answer (really).. :) :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Just to be clear, Hom(M,N) denotes the sheaf whose S-points are smooth maps S⨯M→N.  In particular, the points of Hom(M,N) are precisely the smooth maps M→N.  Hom is right adjoint to the (categorical cartesian) product of sheaves of sets, defined objectwise: (F⨯G)(S)=F(S)⨯G(S).

Comment: Yes, I saw that explanation only recently.. I am still trying to look at the motivation behind such description of the inner-hom/internal-hom $\text{Hom}(M,N)$.. I am reading MacLane and Moedijk's Sheaves in Geometry and Logic (3.6 first properties of categories of sheaves).. Do you have any suggestion on any other book that I should be looking at?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour, Diffeology.  It's all about diffeological spaces (and sheaves of sets on manifolds).

Comment: That book looks interesting (too lengthy though:)) but I do not see where does they talk about the internal hom description :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Sections 1.57–1.65.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at table of contents and was lost in 8+ table of contents. Thanks for the reference. I feel like I might enjoy reading parts of this book.

Comment: For anyone else looking for more references, they can see “17.7 Internal Hom” of Masaki Kashiwara and Pierre Schapira’s book titled “Categories and Sheaves”.